# WPF ControlTemplate with foreach?

Tags: wpf, foreach, controltemplate

I currently try to create classes for a paint-like WPF application. I have to base classes LineMovement (line from StartPoint to EndPoint) and PathMovement (line going through all points specified in a property Points of type PointCollection). These classes inherit from Control and get their looks through a ControlTemplate.

Now I want to add (what I call) PointMovers to the ControlTemplate. These should be little visual elements residing on each of the points in either of the Movement classes. They should become a kind of grip mechanism to drag the underlying point around.

The problem is of course that I don't know a way to create a variable number of elements in a ControlTemplate. It would be cool if I could do something like this:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type mov:PathMovement}" TargetType="{x:Type mov:PathMovement}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type mov:PathMovement}">
                <Grid>
                    <Polyline Points="{TemplateBinding Points}" />
                    <!-- interesting part start -->
                    <foreach loopvariable="Point" in="{TemplateBinding Points}">
                        <PointMover Point="Point" />
                    </foreach>
                    <!-- interesting part end -->
                </Grid>
           </ControlTemplate>
       </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Is this possible? Do you have another approach in mind that could work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `ItemsControl` in conjunction with an `ItemTemplate`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Points}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- rendered for each point -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

By the sounds of your use case, you may also want to read up on `AdornerLayer`s.

Comment: Looks good. I'm gonna try that. 

However regarding your advice with the AdornerLayers: I read there is no way to specify them in XAML so I won't use it (to not mix XAML and code more than absolutely needed).